# Tracking detail in marketing cloud and salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

Is it possible if we send an email from salesforce and we can check the status of that send in marketing cloud my tracking ?

Salesforce and marketing cloud is connected.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best used the other way round, but if absolutely needed...

A workaround could be to;

1. set up a 'report' in Salesforce CRM that pulls in the send data of
   Salesforce CRM emails (by template or job)
2. Save report to 'Marketing Cloud Admin' folder, which will then push into a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud.
3. Run a query to combine data set of sends (need to ensure IDs are mapped in Audience Builder - makes this more straight forward than mapping in queries).